# unfortunately camera has stopped" while using Content Provider

Tags: android, crash, android-contentprovider, android-camera-intent

[image]If I use ContentProvider in my app am getting error like "unfortunately camera has stopped" after Result_ok.This is my code:

```
Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, MyFileContentProvider.CONTENT_URI);
 startActivityForResult(i, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

How to to solve this?I don't want to save image in sd card.

This my MyFileContentProvider class:

```
public class MyFileContentProvider extends ContentProvider {

    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://com.example.user.studentadmission/");
    private static final HashMap<String, String> MIME_TYPES = new HashMap<String, String>();
    static {
        MIME_TYPES.put(".jpg", "image/jpeg");
        MIME_TYPES.put(".jpeg", "image/jpeg");
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        try {
            File mFile = new File(getContext().getFilesDir(), "student.jpg");
            if(!mFile.exists()) {
                mFile.createNewFile();
            }
            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(CONTENT_URI, null);
            return (true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getType(Uri uri) {
        String path = uri.toString();
        for (String extension : MIME_TYPES.keySet()) {
            if (path.endsWith(extension)) {
                return (MIME_TYPES.get(extension));
            }
        }
        return (null);
    }

    @Override
    public ParcelFileDescriptor openFile(Uri uri, String mode)
            throws FileNotFoundException {
        File f = new File(getContext().getFilesDir(), "student.jpg");
        if (f.exists()) {
            return (ParcelFileDescriptor.open(f,
                    ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_WRITE));
        }
        throw new FileNotFoundException(uri.getPath());
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri url, String[] projection, String selection,
                        String[] selectionArgs, String sort) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Operation not supported");
    }

    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues initialValues) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Operation not supported");
    }

    @Override
    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String where,
                      String[] whereArgs) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Operation not supported");
    }

    @Override
    public int delete(Uri uri, String where, String[] whereArgs) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Operation not supported");
    }

}
```

Comment: Post your logcat message. That would be helpful to understand the problem.

Comment: @Amshu I suggest you to go through [this](https://github.com/google/cameraview) example, its a good one.

Comment: @ajantha I am not getting any messages in logcat.

Comment: Are u using intent to capture image only? and what is contect provider working here.

Comment: @W4R10CK worked on some devices.In one mobile I was getting this error.I am using intent to capture image only. I have edited my question and included class MyFileContentProvider now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few camera action works only on `Kitkat`, use condition for action:

```
Intent i = (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
                        ? new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE_SECURE)
                        : new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, MyFileContentProvider.CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(i, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

If still crash occur, try avoiding ContentProvider just for testing. Let me know.

Comment: still am getting same error.This error is in version 5.1 and its working fine in version 6.0.1

Comment: If I comment i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, MyFileContentProvider.CONTENT_URI); there is no problem.But the image quality will be blur.

Comment: The blur image has nothing to do with content provider. Try not using it.

Comment: can u add a image to show what kind of blur u getting. It all about camera.

Comment: please add your contentProvider class.

Comment: when I use   Bitmap imageData = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); in  onActivityResult it will be blur.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123496/discussion-between-amshu-and-w4r10ck).

Comment: can either of you kindly share what is the final solution? thx

Answer (score 0):

Give permission for open Camera.
Give run-time permission for open Camera.